# What's the meaning of "so in"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, synonyms, phrasal-verbs

I couldn't find anything about "so in" in my research on Google. I heard people say it. And today I saw that on a Facebook post. So here's the context-

> You want long hair but short hair is so in and trendy.

I want to know it's exact meaning, also please provide some example.

Answer (score 3):

It means *fashionable* and it is informal when used with this meaning:

> in 
> INFORMAL
> fashionable.
>
> - Pastels and light colours are ***in*** this year. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=in%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsYGle8VFwWrnplEoUBzSW9q718B4Q%3A1658679083145&ei=K2_dYvzHCJS4gQa0taH4Ag&ved=0ahUKEwi8ibCM9ZH5AhUUXMAKHbRaCC8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=in%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6BwgAELEDEEM6BwgAEIAEEApKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQnglYsQxgxhFoAnABeACAAVGIAdsBkgEBM5gBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in) gives other common phrases where ***in*** is used in this sense:

> extremely fashionable
>
> - the ***in*** thing to do
>
> keenly aware of and responsive to what is new and fashionable
>
> - the ***in*** crowd

When used with this meaning, ***in*** is an adjective and so it is no surprise it is accompanied by the [*intensifier*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/intensifiers-very-at-all) ***so***.

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=in), ***in*** has been used with the meaning

> of "stylish, fashionable" from 1960.

Therefore, your sentence means

> You want long hair but short hair is so *fashionable* and trendy.

Comment: Is there any other meaning of "in" except "fashionable". Because I heard people say "this is so in". I don't remember the context but I thought it means "this is so good".

Comment: Without context, it's hard to say. If you look up IN in dictionaries (as an adjective) you will not find good in its meanings. You will find [_inner, incoming or inward, holding office, fashionable_](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=in).

Comment: There's no set phrase of so in, and together they mean very popular. But deserving an erudite answer? Not so in.

Answer (score 1):

> "short hair is so in"

could be translated as

> "short hair is very trendy"

["So" is a not rare synonym of very](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so) (def 2b). It acts in many ways but its most common is as an adverb for intensifying.

"In", while usually a preposition, [is here used as an adjective for 'a la mode' or 'fashionable'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in) (def adj 3a). It is very slangy when used this way, but for the moment seems to be so in.

Comment: When this slang term was first used in the 1960s, it was invariably enclosed in quotes, e.g. _The “pretty girl” look is “in” this season_ (Fashion article, 1968).  It is still used this way sometimes _Recycling clothes is 'in' this season_ (Blog, August 2020).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It was inclosed in quotes because it was a new, strange, uncommon thing, a reuse of a preposition as an adjective. I think it currently still sounds a little "outré", but the lack of quotes is less about people getting used to it and not needing quotes to point it out, and more about textspeak and typing shortcuts and not wanting to waste time with the shift key.